# Call to undefined method access manager controller.php joomla

Tags: component

I have installed an Extension Manager 
Installation was successful but after clicking that Component it shows me this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined method accessmanagerController::check_demo_time_left() in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsite\administrator\components\com_accessmanager\controller.php on line 144

I have received this error before also with other extensions
How should i solve this one ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually post these sorts of comments as answer but thought I would just get straight to the point. `com_accessmanager` is not a part of Joomla's core. It's a 3rd party extension.

The error you're receiving is nothing to do with installing extensions or Joomla itself, therefore the issue should be followed up with the developer of that extension. Before doing so, just ensure you are running the latest version of `com_accessmanager` as the error might have been fixed in a newer version. As a matter of fact, if I'm correct in assuming you're using [this extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control/19766), then an update was actually released today.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have received this before, and assuming it is a different component here is some things to consider.

Most extensions are built on a linux virtual machine and not windows `C:\xampp\` is a windows path `/home/user/public_html` is a linux path. Notice the different slashes? This can be a big problem for some applications. Most developers and the Joomla core do get around this, but not all extension developers may see the need, as so few sites end up on a windows server.

The best way to do a local test is to install something like VirtualBox, there are others but this one is free.
https://www.virtualbox.org/

This will let you get a linux OS like ubuntu or debian (redhat, centos, the list goes on) and use that for your dev environment. Although you should be perfectly fine using xampp in my experience its best to go with the most widely used when needing compatibility.

This in no way will really answer what the actual problem is, but a way to reduce the probability of extensions having some sort of problem based on the environment. If being in a linux environment does not fix it then its quite possible that it is a bug in the component or some hidden problem occurred during install. Possibly even the component came with a plugin that needs to be enabled for it to work.

Personally I am unfamiliar with the extension you are using, so this is just some guesses/suggestions.